# Blend for visual studio 2019 disabled PATH and other shapes in asset window

Tags: uwp-xaml, xaml-designer

I am using Blend for visual studio 2019  Community edition to design XAML pages for my UWP app.
As per the Microsoft document [draw a shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/draw-shapes-and-paths?view=vs-2019)   there should be 6 shapes available(Ellipse, path, line, and other 6) but in my case, these are not available.
Some features like Format-->Convert to motion path also disabled.

Anyone has an idea of what going wrong here I have installed complete vs2019 community edition.

Comment: goto Tools>Choose Toolbox Items> in WPF Components tab,  tick on all tools you want (Eclipse, path, line etc)

Comment: @HarshitPanchal thanks but i am asking about UWP app In Expression blend 2019 not in WPF in WPF type of project those are already available

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Path is not currently available for UWP apps that have a minimum TargetPlatformVersion of 10.0.16299.0 or later.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/draw-shapes-and-paths?view=vs-2019)

Comment: It doesn't work at all in Blend 2022, even if you select old "WPF App (.NET Framework)" template and set target to old 4.6.1 framework.